# I'm getting a stackoverflowexception and i'm not sure why

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

I made a custom user control and am having trouble setting a custom property. This is the code I'm having trouble with, I'm not sure why I'm getting the stack overflow exception. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
displayList = new List<ItemDisplay>();
foreach (var item in InventoryData2.Items)
{
    ItemDisplay id = new ItemDisplay();
    id.Item = item;
    id.Name = item.Item.ItemNumber;
    id.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, displayList.Count * id.Height);
    displayList.Add(id);
}


public InventoryItem Item 
{
    get { return Item; }
    set { 
        Item = value;
        lblItemNumber.Text = Item.Item.ItemNumber;
        lblTitle.Text = Item.Item.Title;
        lblModel.Text = Item.Item.Model;
        lblPrice.Text = Item.Item.Price.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error and stack trace?

Comment: Dare I say it, you came to the right place!

Comment: I assume you'll have to change `return Item` to `return this.Item` but my ad-hoc knowledge of the language being not up to par, I might be completely missing the bat.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Then why answer?

Comment: @DarrinDoherty - Because I *think* it answers the question and helps OP. Looking at the answers posted later on, I now *think* I was right <g>.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I _think_ you saw the problem correctly, but your suggested solution was not correct. I do think you were right to post your comment though, as it might have helped OP. We should not be (made) afraid to help.

Answer (score 8):

The getter of this property will cause infinite recursion:

```
public InventoryItem Item { get { return Item; }
```

So will the setter:

```
set 
{ 
    Item = value;
```

You probably want something like this:

```
private InventoryItem item;

public InventoryItem Item 
{
    get 
    { 
        return this.item; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        this.item = value;
        lblItemNumber.Text = value.Item.ItemNumber;
        lblTitle.Text = value.Item.Title;
        lblModel.Text = value.Item.Model;
        lblPrice.Text = value.Item.Price.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Kris is right, you're setter is recursive (`Item = value;` calls the setter on itself).

Answer (score 2):

You have a "recursive" property access:

```
public InventoryItem Item 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return Item; // <-- "recursive" getter
    }
    set 
    { 
        Item = value; // <-- "recursive" setter
        lblItemNumber.Text = Item.Item.ItemNumber;
        lblTitle.Text = Item.Item.Title;
        lblModel.Text = Item.Item.Model;
        lblPrice.Text = Item.Item.Price.ToString();
    }
}
```

This should look like this (with a backing field):

```
private InventoryItem item;
public InventoryItem Item 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return item; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        item = value;
        lblItemNumber.Text = item.Item.ItemNumber;
        lblTitle.Text = item.Item.Title;
        lblModel.Text = item.Item.Model;
        lblPrice.Text = item.Item.Price.ToString();
    }
}
```